# Understanding a statement in Hatcher about lifting maps in the special case of paths

Tags: algebraic-topology

The following statement is from Hatcher's Algebraic Topology on page 30:

> Given a map $F: Y\times I \to X$ and a map $\tilde{F} : Y\times \{0\} \to \tilde{X}$ lifting $F|Y\times \{0\}$, then there is a unique map $\tilde{F}:Y\times I \to \tilde{X}$ lifting F and restricting to the given $F$ on $Y\times \{0\}$.

I wonder how this applies to the special case of paths by considering $Y$ as a point. Is the map $\tilde{F} : Y\times \{0\} \to \tilde{X}$ the lift of the starting point? I am also confused about "restricting to the given $F$ on $Y\times \{0\}$".

Answer (score 1):

In the case that $Y$ is a point, the map $\tilde{F} : Y\times\{0\} \to \tilde{X}$ is a lift of the starting point.

Note that Hatcher actually writes "... restricting to the given $\tilde{F}$ on $Y\times\{0\}$." When $Y$ is a point, this means that $\tilde{F}$ is a path in $\tilde{X}$ which lifts the path $F : Y\times I \to X$ and has as its starting point the one given by $\tilde{F} : Y\times\{0\} \to \tilde{X}$.