# Understanding hatcher proof of theorem 1.7 i.e $\mathbb{Z}\cong \pi_1(S^1)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am self studying hatcher proof of theorem 1.7 that is $\mathbb{Z}\cong \pi_1(S^1)$ on page 29-30. I have seen the question[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4209249/711852) but i couldn't understand.

Consider these lemmas

(a) For each path $f : I→X$ starting at a point $x_0 ∈ X$ and each $\tilde{x_0} ∈ p^{−1}(x_0)$ there is a unique lift $\tilde{f} : I→\tilde{X}$ starting at $\tilde{x_0}$

(b) For each homotopy $f_t: I→X$ of paths starting at $x_0$ and each $\tilde{x_0} ∈ p^{−1}(x_0)$ there is a unique lifted homotopy $\tilde{f_t}: I→\tilde{X}$ of paths starting at $\tilde{x_0}$

(C) Given a map $F : Y ×I→X$ and a map $\tilde{F}:Y\times\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ lifting $F\big|_{Y\times\{0\}}$, then there is a unique map $\tilde{F} : Y ×I→\tilde{X}$ lifting $F$ and restricting to the given $\tilde{F}$ on $Y × {0}$

Now hatcher says (a) (b) are special cases of (C)  when $Y={ y_0 }$ is a single point and $Y=I$ is the unit interval respectively.

But i can't understand . If someone please explain in detail it will be very helpful

Comment: Is the question how do you see (a) and (b) as a consequence of (c)?

Comment: @Mr.Brown Yeah.How a and b are special case of c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (a), if $Y=x_o\in X$, then $Y\times I=x_o\times I \cong I$. Then a lift of $Y\times 0 =  x_o\times 0\cong x_o$ is just a lift of a $x_o$ to a point $\tilde{x}_o$. Applying $(c)$, this implies we can uniquely lift paths upon choosing $\tilde{x}_o$.

For (b), if $Y=I$ then $Y\times I=I\times I$. Think of the left factor of $I$ as space, and the right factor of $I$ as time. Given a map $f_t:I\times I\to X$, fixing any time $t_o$ gives a map $f_{t_o}:I\times t_o\cong I\to X$, i.e. a path into $X$. From (a), fixing some point $\tilde{x}_o$ in the preimage of $x_o$ implies we can uniquely lift the path $f_0$. But this puts us in a position to invoke (c) to lift the entire map $f_t$. Thus, we lift the homotopy upon choosing $\tilde{x}_o$.

Comment: For part a if $Y\times 0 =  x_o\times 0\cong x_o$ then according to c a map $\tilde{F}:Y\times\{0\}=x_0 \to\mathbb{R}$ lifting $F\big|_{Y\times\{0\}}=F|x_0$. What does it mean?

Comment: A lift of $x_0\times 0$ is nothing more than a choice of preimage $\tilde{x}_o$.

Comment: Why $Y=x_o\in X$ ?,$ Y=y_0$ why single point Y will be an element of X?

Comment: Because I can choose $Y$ as I please. There is no mention of any $y_o$ anywhere in my answer.

Comment: thank you very much for explaining